# firebase realtime database transaction cause listener callback with data that not committed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase realtime database for android, doing transaction to update an object, what suppose to block 2 users from overriding one each other. that seems to work.

**The problem**: one user blocked from writing so `doTransation()` will be called again as should.
According to my logic below first doTransation call won't take affect on the server. second doTransation call will do abort.
after the first doTransation and before the second, I getting the callback `onDataChange()` to my ValueEventListener with the data that was rejected/ not committed and before `onComplete()` called.

any idea why this behavior? how do I change it?

```
fun onIconClicked(currentGameState: GameState, gameId: String, iconClicked: Long) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onIconClicked() called")

    database.child(GAME_STATE_PATH).child(gameId).runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {
        override fun doTransaction(currentData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {

            val gameState = currentData.getValue(GameState::class.java)
                ?: return Transaction.success(currentData)

            // make sure the state from server match the client, and check if won the card        
            return if (gameState == currentGameState && true == currentGameState.users?.get(currentUserId)?.card?.contains(iconClicked) &&
                    true == currentGameState.mainCard?.contains(iconClicked)) {

                // player won card - make the changes in game state...

                currentData.value = gameState
                Log.d(TAG, "doTransaction() winning card, game after = $gameState")

                Transaction.success(currentData)
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "doTransaction() aborting")
                Transaction.abort()
            }
        }

        override fun onComplete(error: DatabaseError?, committed: Boolean, currentData: DataSnapshot?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIconClicked onComplete() called with: error = $error, committed = $committed, currentData = $currentData")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem, and the data you are getting from the SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo added, thanks!

Comment: So you get an error message? What is that message?

Comment: @AlexMamo there's no error. the client that try to doTransaction but not committing anything get the not committed data through the listener. read my question again pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I getting the callback `onDataChange()` to my `ValueEventListener` with the data that was rejected/ not committed and before `onComplete()` called.

Listeners on the same client where the transaction runs will indeed see local events for intermediate transaction iterations.

If you don't want these local events to fire, use the overload of [`runTransaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#runTransaction(com.google.firebase.database.Transaction.Handler,%20boolean)) that takes a second argument called `fireLocalEvents`, and pass `false` for that.

So:

```
database.child(GAME_STATE_PATH).child(gameId).runTransaction(..., false)
```

Comment: thanks! seems like false should be the default and not true or maybe no default at all. pls consider adding it to the basic use documentation cause I couldn't find it anywhere